# Grepping stdin and piping to sed does not seem to work

Tags: grep, replace

I'm trying to filter and replace a standard input in order to capture only specific strings tweaked toward my flavor. For example, say that the standard input string is

```
"KB: the system ran into a critical error"
```

Then I will grep this line, change "KB:" into "###", then output to STDOUT such that

```
"### the system ran into a critical error"
```

I tried in Fedora 12 (and actually in many others)

```
$ grep "KB:" - | sed -e 's/KB:/###/g'
KB: the system ran into a critical error <--- This is what I typed in manually.
                                         <--- Nothing is printed
```

I created a text file, text.txt, that contains the same example string, then had `grep` read from the file like:

```
$ grep "KB:" text.txt | sed -e 's/KB:/###/g'
### the system ran into a critical error <--- Correctly displayed
$
```

What would be the difference seen from the internals of `grep/sed` and why the STDIN method does not work? Rather than hear about alternatives like using `xargs` etc, I want to know why my try should fail.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

`echo "KB: the system ran into a critical error" | grep "KB:" | sed -e 's/KB:/###/g'`

note the exclusion of the `-` character in the `grep` command.

And using `grep` is useless here. You can cut your code down to size:

`echo "KB: the system ran into a critical error" | sed -e 's/KB:/###/g'`
    `### the system ran into a critical error`